# Not possible to remove paragraph dynamicaly

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="div1">
    <button id="btn1">click me to show line </button>
    <button id="btn2">click me to hide line </button>
  </div>
  <script>
    var lines = ["line1", "line2", "line3"];
    var button1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
    button1.addEventListener("click", myfunction1);
    function myfunction1 () {
      var show = document.getElementById("div1");
      var crt = document.createElement("p");
      crt.innerText = lines[0];
      show.appendChild(crt);
    }
    var button2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
    button2.addEventListener("click", myfunction2);
    function myfunction2 () {
      var hide = document.querySelector("p");
      hide.remove();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

With the above code I would like when I click the first button to display text from the array and when I click the second button to delete it. My problem is that it is not deleted by clicking the second button.

Comment: do you have a workable example you can provide, there seems to be a lot of filler text in your question.

Comment: I moved your code into a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/438273) so that others can reproduce your issue. After doing so, it looks to me like it works. Do you think you might have had a typo in the original code?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74817367/not-possible-to-remove-paragraph-dynamicaly#comment132040341_74817367) It appears that you updated the `id` attribute of the second button to `btn2` in [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74817367/4) which fixed your described problem.

Answer (score 0):

The id of your second button is the same as the first. It must be `btn2`.